# Share price of a specific date using google finance

Tags: price, google-finance

How can I get the closing price on specific date for a stock using google finance?

I have tried using =GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:RELIANCE","price",2023-9-13). But of no use, its showing error *:When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'NSE:RELIANCE' returned no data"*

what's the correct formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
index(googlefinance(NSE:Reliance,"Price",'date'),2,2)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).